# Why do i get a unexpected 'endwhile' ? WordPress Theme Development

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am on my way to make a theme for Wordpress, but I've got an issue that is close to make me pull hair out of my head :D

So I get this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'endwhile' (T_ENDWHILE), expecting elseif (T_ELSEIF) or else (T_ELSE) or endif (T_ENDIF) in /app/public/wp-content/themes/mazeit/index.php on line 398

I am trying to make a blog on the frontpage, where it will display the thumbnail, here is the code for it.

```
<div class="row">
          <?php if(have_posts()) : ?>
            <?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 mb-lg-0 mb-4">
                <article class="blog-post">
                <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>
                    <div class="post-thumbnail">
                      <?php the_post_tumbnail(); ?>
                        <ul class="meta-info list-inline">
                            <li class="posted-by">Skrevet af: <a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url(get_the_author_meta('ID') ); ?>"><?php the_author(); ?></a></li>
                            <li class="post-date"><a href="#"><?php the_time('d/m/Y'); ?></a></li>
                            <li class="tags"> Kategori: <a href="#">
                              <?php
                              $categories = get_the_category();
                              $separator = ", ";
                              $output = '';
                              if ($categories) {
                                foreach ($categories as $category) {
                                  $output .= '<a href="'.get_category_link($category->term_id).'">'.$category->cat_name.'</a>'. $separator;
                                }
                              }
                              echo trim($output, $separator);

                              ?>
                           </a>
                         </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="post-content">
                        <div class="post-content-inner">
                            <h5 class="post-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> <?php the_title(); ?></a></h5>
                            <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="read-more-wrapper">
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="read-more-link">Læs mere</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </article>
            </div>
          <?php endwhile; ?>
          <?php else : ?>
            <?php echo apautop('Her er der ikke meget..'); ?>
            <?php endif; ?>


        </div>
```

I hope that somebody can help me out here.

Comment: Because you still have an `if` open.

Comment: Yup unclosed IF after the post thumbnail part, just like the error message says

Comment: it is expecting you to close this first : `<?php if(has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>`